# Polylang Plugin - Content Switches to Default Language on Tablet and Phone Screens

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, permalinks, polylang, language-switching

I have successfully installed the Polylang plugin(Free version) on my WordPress site, and everything seems to be functioning correctly. However, I've encountered an issue when viewing the site on smaller screens, such as tablets or phones.

When the screen size is reduced, all the content on the page switches to the default language, ignoring the selected language. This behavior is not observed on larger screens.

Verified correct installation and configuration of the Polylang plugin.
Ensured the theme is responsive and designed to adapt to different screen sizes.
Checked Polylang settings for language switcher and detection configurations.

Comment: Detect browser language?